# Dynamic sort by properties of inner list

Tags: c#, sorting, dynamic

I have this kind of structure:

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List <Field> Fields;
}

public class Field
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

So it's my custom classes representing record with fields.

Now, I have lots of records `List<Record> Records` and I want to be able to sort records via field(s) values (from `Field.Value`).

Because Field class contains Id property I have a list (`List<int> SortByFieldIds`) that shows which fields I have to use for sort.

My problem is that I don't know how to handle it. I don't know how write a method that takes a `List<Record> RecordsToSort` and `List<int> SortByFieldIds` and returns sorted list of my records. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to sort the list. Something like:

```
List<Record> list = new List<Record>();
List<Record> SortByFieldIds = list.OrderBy(r => r.Fields.Select(a => a.Id)).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to search for the ID first and then sort based on the value try:

```
int yourFieldID = 0;//this will hold your Field.ID
List<Record> sortByFieldId = list.OrderBy(
                                          r => r.Fields.Where(
                                          a => a.Id == yourFieldID
                                          ).FirstOrDefault().Value).ToList();
```

**End EDIT**

To sort the Record list based on the ID

```
List<Record> sortByRecordId = list.OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();
```

Remember to include

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I don't need to order by Field.Id but first I have to get right Field (using Field.Id) and then sort records by this field value (Field.Value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422)

You can make SortByFieldIds at class level, and pass [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf) to OrderBy

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have a `List<int>` of IDs I presume you want to do a filtering
based on those IDs against the `List<Field>` of the `Records` on the `ID` property of the `Field`
& finally sort the Fields based on the IDs.

So for example if there are 2 records

```
record 1 has 3 fields with IDs (1,2,3)
record 2 had 4 fields with IDs (4,3,6,2)
```

now if `List<int>` has values `6,2,3` you want the records to be returned with fields that are with IDs 6,2,3 and the fields need to be sorted for each record.

So with the example case your results would be

```
record 1 has 3 fields with IDs (2,3)
record 2 had 4 fields with IDS (2,3,6)
```

**If this is the one you are after then here is the code for an actual example**

```
        List<Field> fields1 = new List<Field>();
        fields1.Add(new Field() { Id = 1, Name = "ONE", Value = "one" });
        fields1.Add(new Field() { Id = 2, Name = "TWO", Value = "two" });
        fields1.Add(new Field() { Id = 3, Name = "THREE", Value = "three" });

        List<Field> fields2 = new List<Field>();
        fields2.Add(new Field() { Id = 4, Name = "FOUR", Value = "four" });            
        fields2.Add(new Field() { Id = 3, Name = "THREE", Value = "three" });
        fields2.Add(new Field() { Id = 6, Name = "SIX", Value = "six" });
        fields2.Add(new Field() { Id = 2, Name = "TWO", Value = "two" });

        records.Add(new Record() { Id = 1, Fields = fields1 });
        records.Add(new Record() { Id = 2, Fields = fields2 });

        //You did mention that you already have this 
        List<int> SortByFieldIds = new List<int>();
        SortByFieldIds.AddRange(new List<int> { 6, 2, 3 });


        //before foreach loop records will have 2 records (record1 with fields 1,2,3 and record2 with fields 4,3,6,2)

        foreach (Record r in records)
        {
            r.Fields = r.Fields.Where(f => SortByFieldIds.Contains(f.Id)).OrderBy(f => f.Id).ToList();
        }

        //after foreach loop records will have 2 records (record1 with fields 2,3 and record2 with fields 2,3,6)
```